# How can I center align subsection heading in an AMSBOOK document

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, amsbook

In an amsbook based document A subsection heading seems to be left aligned with some indentation in the beginning. Chapter and section headings are center aligned. How can I make subsections also center aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the definition in `amsbook` specifies paragraph indentation at the beginning and a run-in heading.  those have to be overruled.  this code will do it:

```
\makeatletter
    \def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
      \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.25\linespacing}%
      {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}}
\makeatother
```

i've set the spacing below the heading (`.25\linespacing`) to be just half of the (minimum) spacing above, so the following text will be closer to the heading than what's above it.

Comment: Thanx. This does work.